# How to allow one-time use of a web application?

Tags: web-applications

I am looking for a way to allow a user to use my app once. The reason is because I am making a quiz and I don't want people to do the quiz a second time and make another entry on my database. I am using React, Express and postgresql.

I was thinking about restricting the user's by IP address. But the issue with that is that there are dynamic ip's.
Another idea was to make a sign-up from google, facebook and create a key for every user. The issue with that is that people can create another e-mail. But this one is probably the best solution.

Maybe you guys have some better ideas. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: How robust do you want to make this? There will be a direct correlation between how hard your app is to use for end users, versus how certain you can be about getting just one entry per person. The extreme "I must guarantee this" level is quite hard to achieve.

Comment: As certain as possible and as easy as possible preferably. How would you achieve this in a theoretical manner? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem to solve, and involves trade-offs. The more robust your protection is, the more hurdles you must put in front of users.

There are a few common-ish solutions to this.

**IP address** - no hurdles to the user, but very unreliable - most ISPs assign different IP addresses to the same user for different browsing sessions.

**Cookies** - you can place a cookie on the browser after the user completes the quiz. No hurdles to the user, but trivially easy to circumvent by removing the cookie, and users may use different devices.

**Login/registration scheme** - you can require users to authenticate before completing the quiz, and verify their email address, or phone number. This creates a hurdle for users - not all will want to do this. Easy to circumvent by using multiple email addresses and burner phones.

**3rd party authentication** - you could require users to authenticate using a 3rd party identity provider. Sites like Facebook are pretty good at weeding out false profiles. This would place an additional hurdle in front of users - not everyone has a facebook profile, or wants you to know about it. Pretty tricky to circumvent though, as long as you only allow one 3rd party identity provider, and they have a good "no fake profiles" policy.

**Strong authentication** - applications which require unambiguous, proven identity use strong authentication. Examples include online banking, and (in the UK) tax submission. These applications typically require submission of some other proof of identity like a photo of your passport. Huge hurdle to users, and only really viable for must-have apps.